# Comparando 2 campos senha se são iguais

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um campo senha e confirmar senha, desejo verificar se ambos são iguais.

OBS: Existe um autocomplete OFF para o campo de e-mail

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtEmail').attr('autocomplete','off');

    if( $('#txtSenha').val() != $('#txtSenhaConfirme').val()   )
    {
        alert('Senhas diferentes');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Não da erro de JS, apenas não funciona.
OBS: Mesmo corrigido o erro de digitação, ainda não valida.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/101

Comment: Cara, depois do diferente falta um "$("
Será isso o erro?

Comment: Não relacionado, mas não se esqueça de também fazer uma validação *server side* (o JavaScript pode estar desativado no cliente, ou mesmo ser manipulado por um usuário experiente).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem alguns erros no seu código, sintaxe inválida (falta `$(` no `#txtSenhaConfirme`).

De qualquer forma duvido que queira fazer essa verificação diretamente aqui `$(document).ready(function () {` pois isso quer dizer basicamente "quando a página acabou de carregar".

Para verificar dois valores pode usar o `.value` ou `.val()` dependendo de estar a usar JavaScript puro ou jQuery.

Assim, e provavelmente dentro de uma função, ou de um evento como o submit, pode fazer assim:

```
if($('#txtSenha').val() != $('#txtSenhaConfirme').val()){
    alert('Senhas diferentes');
    return false;
}
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    if ($('#txtSenha').val() != $('#txtSenhaConfirme').val()) {
        alert('Senhas diferentes');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="txtSenha" />
    <input type="text" id="txtSenhaConfirme" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: ok, falha minha no digitar, porém ainda esta enviando sem validar!

Comment: @Dorathoto então tem de colocar _todo_ o seu código para poder ver onde pode ter outros problemas

Answer (score 2):

O erro esta acontecendo é esse:

```
$('#txtSenha').val() != '#txtSenhaConfirme').val()
```

esta esquecendo de um `$(` enquanto o correto seria:

```
$('#txtSenha').val() != $('#txtSenhaConfirme').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tive problemas em alguns navegadores (IE7, IE6) com o `.val()`. Vale a pena tentar `$('#txtSenha').text() != '#txtSenhaConfirme').text()`